# Unable to wake Windows 10 from sleep when using USB KB/Mouse switch

Tags: windows-10, usb, sleep

I have a Win10 desktop, and I'm using a Rosewill USB 2.0 Sharing Switch Box to share the kb/mouse with my Mac. I have Windows setup to sleep after 15 mins, and if I just walk away for 15 mins and return, I can wake the PC with the kb/mouse. However, if I use the button on the USB switch before the PC goes to sleep (to switch the inputs to the Mac), then I'm unable to wake it with the kb/mouse after switching the inputs back.

I've found the USB switch in device manager, and unchecked the box for "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power", but that didn't help. Both devices are found in the output of `powercfg /devicequery wake_armed`. Any ideas?

Comment: Windows 10 lost the keyboard (just like unplugging it) when it suspended without the keyboard (your comment above). I think that behavior is normal and there isn't much you can do about it. If it were me, I would be inclined to give the machines their own keyboard.

Comment: I think you may be right, but I wanted to poll the experts :) In the meantime, I have a surplus miniature wireless mouse that I've connected directly to the PC, so I can jiggle that to wake it up. Leaving open in the off-chance someone has a better solution.

Comment: If I post a solution like above, will you find that helpful?

Comment: Not sure I follow what you mean.

Comment: My answer above is merely a comment (so will go away in a couple of weeks). I can post it as answer below (which will stay) if you are amenable to that.

Comment: I wasn't aware comments would get pruned, interesting. I don't care if you post it, but I'm not going to accept it since it's not an authoritative solution. E.g. if you can provide documentation of some sort proving that what I'm asking is impossible, then that's a good answer, but IMHO your prior comment doesn't really move the needle much on the conversation. Thank you.

Comment: Read down to the second solution that it is the design of the KVM switch and a suggestion you may need a different kind of switch.  https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/152165-desktop-loses-mouse-keyb-on-usb-kvm